# localStorage does not save/show items

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I do my ToDo list. (I learn vanilla JS). And I have some problem with saving some items to localStorage. When I use Google chrome(F12), I see `undefiend`. Maybe, I do not save correctly to localStorage. I tried to change `var task` to array, but it does not help.  Pleas, show me my mistakes. I know, my code must be rewritten, it is my first code on JS. P.s. in console (in stackOverflow) I have that error

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 348,
  "colno": 6
}
```

but in my browser not.

```js
var task = document.querySelector("ul");
var forTask;
function toLocal(){
    forTask = task.innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem("forLocal",forTask);
}
function newElement(newChild) {
    let btnDel= document.createElement("button");
    btnDel.className = "fa fa-trash-o";
    let myEd = document.getElementById("myEdit");
    let spanClose1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
    let spanRedact = document.getElementsByClassName("redact")[0];
    let myDel = document.getElementById("myDelete");
    let spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    let spanYes = document.getElementsByClassName("yes")[0];
    //create button
    let divWithBut = document.createElement("div");
    divWithBut.className = "forButt";
    let btnRedact = document.createElement("button");
    btnRedact.className = "fa fa-pencil";
    //redact but
    btnRedact.onclick = function(){
        myEd.style.display = "block";
        let editText = document.getElementById("editText");
        let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
        editText.value = divWithText.innerHTML;
        editText.currentTarget;
        spanRedact.onclick = function(){
            divWithText.textContent = editText.value;
            divWithText.className = "todoPost";
            myEd.style.display = "none";
        };
        spanClose1.onclick = function() {
            myEd.style.display = "none";
        };
    }
    /*************************** */
    /*done but*/
    let doneBut = document.createElement("button");
    doneBut.className = "fa fa-check-circle-o";
    doneBut.onclick = function(){
        let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
        divWithText.classList.toggle("checked");
    }
    /******************* */
    divWithBut.appendChild(btnRedact);
    divWithBut.appendChild(doneBut);
    divWithBut.appendChild(btnDel);
    /******************/
//for index
    let indexDiv = document.createElement("div");
    indexDiv.className = "indexDiv";
    let numbInd = 1;
    indexDiv.innerHTML = numbInd;
    /*********************************** */
        //create arrow
    let divWithArrow = document.createElement("div");
    divWithArrow.className = "myArrow";
    let arrowUP = document.createElement("i");
    arrowUP.className = "fa fa-chevron-up";
    let arrowDown = document.createElement("i");
    arrowDown.className = "fa fa-chevron-down";
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowUP);
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowDown);
    //for date
    let date = new Date();
    let curr_date = date.getDate();
    let curr_month = date.getMonth()+1;
    let curr_year = date.getFullYear();
    let curr_hour = date.getHours();
    let curr_minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let d = (curr_date + "." + curr_month + "." + curr_year+"<br>"+curr_hour+":"+curr_minutes);
    let divTime = document.createElement("div");
    divTime.style.textAlign = "center";;
    divTime.innerHTML = d;
    //***************************/
    let div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "timeComent";
    let myli = document.createElement("li");
    myli.className = "todoPost";
    let addField = document.getElementById("addField").value;
    task = document.createTextNode(addField);
    myli.appendChild(task);
    div1.appendChild(divTime);
    div1.appendChild(indexDiv);
    div1.appendChild(divWithArrow);
    div1.appendChild(myli);
    divWithBut.style.display = "flex";
    div1.appendChild(divWithBut);
    if (addField === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("forToDo").appendChild(div1);
        toLocal();
    }
    document.getElementById("addField").value = "";
    //delete but
    btnDel.onclick = function(){
        myDel.style.display = "block";
        spanClose.onclick = function() {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
        };
        spanYes.onclick = function() {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
            div1.remove();
        };
    }
toLocal();
}
if(localStorage.getItem("forLocal")){
    task.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("forLocal");
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{

    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.firstBar{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.indexDiv{
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #888;
}
.fafaArrow{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
}
.timeComent{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
}
.numberpost{
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(141, 112, 112);
}
.todoPost{
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.shadow {
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.window {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #0000cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #0000cc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
}
.shadow:target {display: block;}


.redact {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.redact:hover {
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;}
.close{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close:hover{
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
/* Style the close button */
.close3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.yes {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.yes:hover{
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;
}

.close1{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close1:hover{
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
div li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
div li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TO DO List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <input id="addField" type="text" size="70%" placeholder="Task" name="Task">
    <button type="button" onclick="newElement()">Add</button>
</header>
<div>
    <div class="firstBar">
        <div class="fafaArrow">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ></i>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            <input class="inptxt" type="text" size="50%" name="Task">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <ul id="forToDo" >
    </ul>
<div id="myDelete" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">Delete item?<br>
        <span class="yes">Yes</span>
        <span class="close">No</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myEdit" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">
        Edit text?<br>
        <label>
            <textarea id="editText"></textarea>
        </label>
        <span class="redact">Save</span>
        <span class="close1">Cancel</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code. Can't find it because the error message is quite vague, but it's there.

Comment: Ok, found it. Near the end the call to `toLocal()` should stay on its own line.

Comment: Also, since this escaped you, please check the console for errors and in case [edit] your answer to add them.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I edit my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an element to the page, at a certain point you do this

```
task = document.createTextNode(addField);
```

Since `task` is a global variable (you declared it at the top), you're overshadowing it with the `TextNode` you're creating, so that when you then call `toLocal` and you do

```
forTask = task.innerHTML;
```

`task` has no `innerHTML` attribute, so it returns `undefined`.

Also, for some reason, you call `toLocal` again at the end of `newElement`. It's not *the* problem but it's something you may want to think about. I'm not sure it's what you want.

@TakayashiHarano gave a couple of hints to solve this, but I'm not sure what you want is just to have the latest element in the local storage. So I would re-write `toLocal` so that it takes a string (the text of the item) as input, writes it at the end of a JSON array (already populated with what was in the local storage previously), and puts the array back in local storage.

```
function toLocal(toAdd) {
    let storage = localStorage.getItem('forLocal');
    if (storage === null) {
        storage = [];
    } else {
        storage = JSON.parse(storage);
    }
    storage.push(toAdd);
    localStorage.setItem('forLocal', JSON.stringify(storage));
}
```

Then you should modify the part of the code that reads the local storage (the one at the end) to basically simulate adding a new item as you would do when creating a new task, but for each item in the parsed JSON coming from local storage.

To be fair, your code needs a good dose of rewriting to achieve this, so I'll just leave you with this as an exercise.

Comment: if I am not mistake, method `push()` can not read because array `null`, isn't it?

Comment: when I coded in Java for Android or Desctop, it was easly(((

Comment: that's the reason I'm instantiating it as an empty array if it's not in local storage already. see that `if/else`, that's what it does

Comment: localStorage.getItem() returns a DOMString, or null if the key does not exist. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem 
So the returned value should be compared with null in the "if" statement. 
And @SYVY_UA's original vision will store "undefined" as a DOMString by implicit conversion.

Comment: @TakashiHarano you're right, of course. I fixed the condition, now it checks for `null`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca why localStorage save `null`. And after reboot page I see `null null null`

Comment: @SYVY_UA have you modified the calls to `toLocal` to actually send a string?

Answer (score 0):

The following changes are needed.

1 - Set up two variables separably for the following task variable.

```
var task = document.querySelector("ul");
task = document.createTextNode(addField);
```

For example, "ulElement" for the first one, and "task" for the second one.
This is to prevent to override the previously defined value.

2 - Move the timing for obtaining the ul element and load localStorage.

```
function onReady() {
  ulElement = document.querySelector("ul");
  if(localStorage.getItem("forLocal")){
    ulElement.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("forLocal");
  }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onReady, true);
```

To ensure the element existence, document.querySelector() should be called after the DOMContentLoaded event fired.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

3 - Delete toLocal(); in the end of the newElement() function.
As far as my testing code, there is no need this statement.